# How Can I Run One Form in VS2015?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

How can i run one of my Windows in wpf for seeing or testing without run all project ?
this feature exist in NetBeans (Shift+F6);

Comment: When you say of my "Windows" in a project are you talking about a Form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always just run a single *project*, in fact, thats the default. If for some reason *multiple* projects are starting, you can change which ones start in the solution property window.

You cannot, however, just "run" a WPF window, page, or user control. The designer will try to show you how it will look with whatever data is initialized in the constructor, but thats as good as you are going to get.

To actually run, you have to run the whole program; **period**. Running pieces is not possible.